# React Application to have a staging environment and deploying with Docker on AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, circleci

I am working on a react application created by create-react-app. I have two environments on AWS Elastic BeanStalk, staging and production. I am deploying my application through Docker. I am using CircleCI for automated deployments.

My problem is I want to change the endpoint url while building the react application.

I am using cross-env for setting a variable `REACT_APP_API_HOST` but i have to run a command `build:staging` for building it.

I am not sure how to do it with this docker.

Docker file

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

RUN npm install -g serve

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["serve", "-l", "3000", "-s", "build", "-d"]
```

And the scripts part of package.json file

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "build:staging": "cross-env REACT_APP_API_HOST=staging react-scripts build",
        "build:prod": "cross-env REACT_APP_API_HOST=production react-scripts build"
    },
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after a long R&D, the answer I find with my friend is do run a intermediate script before deploying it to Elastic Beanstalk.

buildDocker.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
branch_name=$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)

if [ "$branch_name" == "develop" ]; then
    result_sed=$(sed 's/RUN npm run build/RUN npm run build:staging/g' Dockerfile)
    echo "$result_sed" > Dockerfile
elif [ "$branch_name" == "master" ]; then
    result_sed=$(sed 's/RUN npm run build/RUN npm run build:prod/g' Dockerfile)
    echo "$result_sed" > Dockerfile
fi
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Just create a different environment for your staging setup and then have CodePipeline integrade with your Bitbucket/Github to listen for changes